# Finding the tangent plane to a paraboloid which is parallel to a given one.

Tags: differential-geometry

> Find the point on the paraboloid $z = 9 − 4x^2 − y^2$ at which the tangent plane is parallel to the plane $z = 4y$.

**My work**: I've gotten gradient $f<x,y,z> = <8x,2y, 1>$ and $g<y,z> = <-4,1>$. Where do I go from here?

Comment: You need to find the point on the plane at which the normal to the paraboloid is paralel to $g$.

Comment: Shouldn't the two gradients have the same number of components?

Comment: meaning $g<x,y,z>=<0,-4,1>$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tangent plane at $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$, a point on the surface $f(x,y,z)=4x^2 +y^2 +z -9=0$, is
$$f_x(x_0,y_0,z_0)(x-x_0)+f_y(x_0,y_0,z_0)(y-y_0)+f_z(x_0,y_0,z_0)(z-z_0)=0$$
that is
$$8x_0(x-x_0)+2y_0(y-y_0)+1(z-z_0)=0.$$
Therefore the tangent plane is parallel to the given plane $0x-4y+z=0$ iff 
$$\mbox{$(8x_0,2y_0,1)$ is parallel to $(0,-4,1)$.}$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: can i do this?

$f<x,y,z>=<8x,2y,1>$ $g<x,y,z>=<0,−4,1>$

$8x=0$
$2y=-4$
$1=1$

therefore P(0,-2,1)?

Comment: I understand $x_0=0$ and $y_0=-2$. Why $z_0=1$? Note that $(0,-2,1)$ is not on the paraboloid.

Comment: I should sub x=0 and y=-2 into the paraboloid and get z = 5?
therefore P(0,-2,5)

Comment: Yes, this is the correct answer!

Comment: So I should not equate 1=1 for the z component right? 
Yup I'm new here, thanks for the help! Will check it out.

Comment: You should equate $1=1$, which holds but it does not give information about $z_0$. But we know that $f(x_0,y_0,z_0)=0$. So...

Comment: I see. Wait what does $f(x0,y0,z0)=0$ mean? Doesn't $f(x0,y0,z0)=9$?

Comment: Sorry, I changed the definition of $f$ in my answer. Just a stylistic matter.

Comment: Oh oops, I missed that. Anyway I got it, thanks for your help!